# PHP : file_get_contents returns email address as [email protected] in response content

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am trying below code to get content of page

```
echo file_get_contents('https://www.somewebsite.com/');
```

everything is working fine but email address is appear as **[email protected]**.I searched on it but find nothing.Please help me with this.

[image]

Comment: can you show screenshot ?

Comment: updated question with screenshot.

Comment: And you can see the email when you enter the website using your browser? If so then most likely they have a simple protection mechanism: by user-agent, cookie maybe or javascript replaces these on the frontend dynamically after the page is loaded.

Comment: Is there any solution for it??

Comment: Any solution till now?

Comment: No solution yet